# Eclipse doesn't find the installed JREs anymore

Tags: eclipse, jvm, eclipse-indigo, java, eclipse-juno

My eclipse doesn't find the installed JREs anymore. When trying to set them up I get an error  message which I attached as a picture. I am running eclipse on ubuntu 12.04, neither my old Eclipse 3.7.2 nor the just downloaded version 4.2 is working. Same error messages is popping up. I tried to use a different Java version (update-alternatives java), changed from openjdk-6 to openjdk-7, same error. Changed the `-vm` parameter in the eclipse.ini to the java path (version) I would like to use, but getting still the error. I don't know what else I can try...

Your help is really appreciated.[image]

Comment: Can you extend the question with the error log?

Comment: I am having exactly the same trouble with the same case: Eclipse 3.7.2 and 4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. When I click on "Show Error Log", nothing happens. It seems the problem appeared after a crash in the update of oracle jdk 7. I have deleted it now and use only the default openJDK, but the problem still persists. There is maybe an eclipse configuration file somewhere to restore with default values... maybe something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this bug following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187043/1058) on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/): Just launch a `sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java`.